# Couldn't find User without an ID, Notifier

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am doing a simple sending of mails with a message and a subject, when I want to send the mail to the destination mail I get the following error, "Couldn't find User without an ID"

I have the following code:

#### app/mailers/notifier.rb:

```rb
def envio_mail(subject, message, user)
  @user = User.find(user)
  @muser = user
  @body_message = message
  mail(:to => @user.email, :subject => subject)
end
```

#### app/controllers/gratitudes_controller.rb:

```rb
def create
  @gratitude = Gratitude.new(params[:gratitude])

  user = params[:user_id]
  Notifier.envio_mail(params[:subject], params[:message], user).deliver

  respond_to do |format|
    if @gratitude.save
      format.html { redirect_to(@gratitude, :notice => 'Gratitude was successfully created.') }
      format.xml  { render :xml => @gratitude, :status => :created, :location => @gratitude }
    else
      format.html { render :action => "new" }
      format.xml  { render :xml => @gratitude.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

This is the error:

```sh
Started POST "/gratitudes" for 127.0.0.1 at 2020-02-26 17:10:55 -0500
Processing by GratitudesController#create as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"iofCtlwd5CE5Zbuo5n6NzCo4Inksht4o05OiiwYUY24=", "gratitude"=>{"subject"=>"asdasd", "message"=>"<p>asda</p>", "user_id"=>"4"}, "commit"=>"Enviar mensaje"}
      SCHEMA (0.6ms)  SHOW TABLES 
      ClientParameterization Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `client_parameterizations`.* FROM `client_parameterizations` LIMIT 1
      User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
      Profile Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `profiles`.* FROM `profiles` WHERE `profiles`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
    Completed 404 Not Found in 130ms

    ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find User without an ID):
      app/mailers/notifier.rb:405:in `envio_mail'
      app/controllers/gratitudes_controller.rb:48:in `create'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should only send the email if the user input is actually valid.

```
 def create
  @gratitude = Gratitude.new(gratitude_params)
  respond_to do |format|
    if @gratitude.save
      Notifier.envio_mail(@gratitude.subject, @gratitude.message, @gratitude.user).deliver
      format.html { redirect_to(@gratitude, notice: 'Gratitude was successfully created.') }
      format.xml  { render xml: @gratitude, status: :created, location: @gratitude }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.xml  { render xml: @gratitude.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end

# ...

private

def gratitude_params
  params.require(:gratitude)
        .permit(:subject, :message, :user_id)
end
```

This assumes that you have some sort of validations in your Gratitude model that validate the presence of the `user_id`, `subject` and `message`.

Comment: I would really consider doing it this way. The problem with model callbacks is that the will fire everywhere like in your tests and sending out emails should NOT be a responsibility of the model.

Comment: you're right, yesterday I looked quickly at the first answer that appeared, today calmly seeing, I see that this answer has what I really needed, obviously, without discrediting the other solutions

Answer (score 1):

In your params `"gratitude"=>{"subject"=>"asdasd", "message"=>"<p>asda</p>", "user_id"=>"4"}`

`user_id` is nested inside `gratitude`, do this to fetch the `user_id`

```
user = params[:gratitude][:user_id]
```

**Suggestion**

To make sure the mail is only sent when a Gratitude is successfully created, you can move the mail trigger to `after_commit` callback in `Gratitude` model

in Gratitude model

```
after_commit :send_mail, on: :create

def send_mail
  Notifier.envio_mail(subject, message, user_id).deliver
end
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: This still does not address the fact that there is no error handling at all in place if that parameter is not passed. A band-aid can't fix a gunshot wound.

Comment: The OP is not asking for help with validation or error handling.

Comment: @dan pretty sure the OP will be back soon or later when this blows up as this is really just a duct tape solution to the wrong problem. It "works" but just if you don't actually care about handling errors...

Comment: it's ok, the answer is valid, in my case, I needed a brief explanation of what was happening. i really appreciate your help! :D

Comment: Why should your model be responsible for sending emails Instead of just fixing the controller?

Comment: If we talk about good practices, I think you're right, thanks for your corrections